# Changed github repo, but still readthedocs auto-building upon commits to old repo

Tags: read-the-docs

I have a project on the read-the-docs that builds automatically upon commits to the github repo. I recently separated out the docs to a separate github repo, and changed "Repository" on read-the-docs appropriately. Indeed, read-the-docs builds the project correctly from the new repo. HOWEVER, the trigger for auto-building is still commits to the old repo, not the new one. Does anyone have any idea how to update the trigger?

Answer (score 1):

The reason for this is that Read the Docs sets an outgoing webhook on your project after you import it, and it probably is still there after you migrate. You should go to [https://github.com/{org}/{old_project}/settings/hooks](https://github.com/%7Borg%7D/%7Bold_project%7D/settings/hooks) and delete it.

Comment: Thank you! Indeed I can see the hook in the old repo, and no hook in the new repo. How do I create a new hook in the new repo?

Comment: Like this: https://docs.readthedocs.io/en/stable/integrations.html#integration-creation